# Android jQuery can't load image from certain server

Tags: java, android, android-query

I'm using jQuery to load some images in to a list view. The image exists under that URL but it wont show, I tried to open an other images on the server but none of them will open. If I upload the same image to Imgur or any other server jQuery can load the image.

Has someone ever encountered a similar problem with jQuery and certain servers?

```
boolean memCache = true;
boolean fileCache = true;

AQuery aq = new AQuery(activity, imageFavorite);
aq.id(R.id.favorite_img).image("http://abc-production.ch/_data/img/icon/20141203-103242-880.jpg", memCache, fileCache);

// Imgur Test
aq.id(R.id.favorite_img).image("http://i.imgur.com/3kQB1o7.jpg", memCache, fileCache);
```

Comment: Have you tried loading those images manually in the phone's browser?

Comment: I tryed to load the image in the webview and there it wont show either, but in the Android Chrome app it shows the image.

Comment: Are you getting any output in LogCat?

Comment: And is it possible that the real filename has characters in it that are getting escaped? You did the right thing in obfuscating the URL, but that URL itself might be the issue.

Comment: My bad, it does work on the webview. I don't get any error message when I load it with Aquery. It fills the list view with the rest of the content but the image container stays empty.